# How to include a prebuilt library on Android?

Tags: android, include-path

I have a 2 prebuilt libFOO.so libraries for android. I have copied them on:

```
Projectfolder/lib/armeabi/libFOO.so

Projectfolder/lib/armeabi/libFOO2.so

Projectfolder/lib/armeabi-v7a/libFOO.so

Projectfolder/lib/armeabi-v7a/libFOO2.so
```

The problem is that when I build the .apk I don't even have the "lib" folder! How can I make eclipse include these libraries on the .apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename the `lib` folder to `libs`. That works for our project. Nevertheless this results in a `lib` folder containing the libraries in your .apk package.

Comment: That was it! As soon as I renamed the lib folder, the folder got the "a" (Android") icon too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put external library in your manifest.xml under `application` tag.

ex : `<uses-library android:name="com.your.external.package" />`